# Issues with accuracy with Bernoulli Number generator in java

Tags: java, for-loop, math, sum, bernoulli-numbers

I've created some code that generates the Bernoulli Numbers based off of formula 33 on MathWorld. This is given at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html and should work for all integers n but it diverges from the expected results extremely quickly once it gets to n=14. I think the issue may be in the factorial code, although I have no idea.

It's pretty accurate up until 13, all odd numbers should be 0 besides 1 but the values past 14 give weird values. For instance 14 gives a number like 0.9 when it should give something around 7/6 and say 22 gives a very negative number in the order of 10^-4. The odd numbers give strange values like 15 gives around -11.

Here is all the related code

```
public static double bernoulliNumber2(int n) {
    double bernoulliN = 0;
    for (double k = 0D; k <= n; k++) {
        bernoulliN += sum2(k,n)/(k+1);
    }
    return bernoulliN;
}
public static double sum2(double k, int n) {
    double result = 0;

    for (double v = 0D; v <= k; v++) {
        result += Math.pow(-1, v) * MathUtils.nCr((int) k,(int) v) * Math.pow(v, n);
    }

    return result;    
}
```

```
public static double nCr(int n, int r) {
    return Factorial.factorial(n) / (Factorial.factorial(n - r) * Factorial.factorial(r));
}
```

```
public static double factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else return (n * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a side note you can definitely look into caching/memoization of factorial results to speed up the program, because that is being computed repeatedly. But that is not a bug, since you are getting a result. None of these calculations should overflow `double` at n=14. It would be helpful if you can share more about the expected vs actual results for each n value.

Comment: Expected values are on the Wolfram article.

Comment: Put any necessary information in your question. And I doubt that the Wolfram article tells us what numbers you are actually seeing.

Comment: Sorry, it's pretty accurate up until 13, all odd numbers should be 0 besides 1 but the values past 14 give weird values. For instance 14 gives a number like 0.9 when it should give something around 7/6 and say 22 gives a very negative number in the order of 10^-4. The odd numbers give strange values like 15 gives around -11.

Comment: I think that large intermediate values are pushing precision you need in the final result out of the mantissa.

Comment: So do you think its the size of the factorial because yeah 14! is big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that floating point arithmetic doesn't need to overflow to experience catastrophic loss of precision.

A floating point number has a mantissa and an exponent, where the value of the number is mantissa * 10^exponent (real floating point numbers use binary, I'm using decimal). The mantissa has limited precision.

When we add floating point numbers of different signs we can end up with a final result which has lost precision.

e.g. let's say the mantissa is 4 digits.
If we add:

1.001 x 10^3 + 1.000 x 10^4 - 1.000 x 10^4

we expect to get 1.001 x 10^3.
But 1.001 x 10^3 + 1.000 x 10^4 = 11.001 x 10^3, which is represented as 1.100 x 10^4, given that our mantissa has only 4 digits.

So when we subtract 1.000 x 10^4 we get 0.100 x 10^4, which is represented as 1.000 x 10^3 rather than 1.001 x 10^3.

Here's an implementation using `BigDecimal` which gives better results (and is far slower).

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class App {
    public static double bernoulliNumber2(int n) {
        BigDecimal bernoulliN = new BigDecimal(0);
        for (long k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            bernoulliN = bernoulliN.add(sum2(k,n));
            //System.out.println("B:" + bernoulliN);
        }
        return bernoulliN.doubleValue();
    }
    public static BigDecimal sum2(long k, int n) {
        BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        for (long v = 0; v <= k; v++) {
            BigDecimal vTon = BigDecimal.valueOf(v).pow(n);
            result = result.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(-1, v)).multiply(nCr(k,v)).multiply(vTon).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(k + 1), 1000, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static BigDecimal nCr(long n, long r) {
        return factorial(n).divide(factorial(n - r)).divide(factorial(r));
    }
    public static BigDecimal factorial(long n) {
        if (n == 0) return BigDecimal.ONE;
        else return factorial(n-1).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(n));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + bernoulliNumber2(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Try changing the scale passed to the division in `sum2` and watch the effect on the output.

Comment: Thank you so much. Although it still diverges past there, I'm getting 15: -23.639285714285716
16: -2245.162672376643
17: -14389.589377452612
18: -147997.97879116068
19: 7.928308554807248E8
20: 2.275498450290969E10
and if I go any further it halts.

Comment: v^n was losing accuracy, I've changed that to use bigdecimal